# Onelogin hides actual referral

Tags: web-analytics, onelogin, referrals, web-analytics-tools, mobile-analytics

We are attempting to track referral source in our app, but most of the referrals are Onelogin, which is hiding the actual referral. How may we obtain the actual referral?